# OutputStream JTextArea Thread.Sleep Causes Freezing

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I'm working on a game project where I'm creating a GUI using JSwing. It looks something like this:

[A lonely 'F'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOfPw.png)

I'm trying to create a 'typewriter' effect, and so have a Thread.sleep(100) in my custom PrintUtils method (let's call it printToGui). I've routed System.out to the TextArea in the center of the GUI, and the first time I run the program the 'typewriter' effect works great and the startup text I send through printToGui shows up as it should. However, whenever I click a button (which triggers more text getting sent through printToGui), the app freezes, and won't unfreeze until the length of time it would have taken to print with Thread.sleep() finishes, spitting out all the text at once.

What I've figured out is that the first time I start the app, Thread.sleep() is happening on the "main" thread, while every time I click a button it's happening on the AWT-EventQueue-0 thread. I assume this is the problem, but maybe it's not; how do I get future output to the GUI to happen on the "main" thread and not the new one? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a Swing timer instead of `Thread.sleep`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html or the duplicates linked at the top of the question body.

Comment: Terrific, thank you!